# Website hiding page footer from parser

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the donation button on the website of
[The University of British Columbia](https://www.ubc.ca/).

The donation button is located at the page footer, within the div classed as "span7"

However, when scraped, the html yeilded the div with nothing inside it.

My program works perfectly with direct div as source:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

site = '''<div class="span7" id="ubc7-footer-menu"><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span6"><h3>About UBC</h3><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/contact">Contact UBC</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/about">About the University</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/news">News</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/events">Events</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/careers">Careers</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/gift">Make a Gift</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/search">Search UBC.ca</a></div></div><div class="span6"><h3>UBC Campuses</h3><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/vancouver">Vancouver Campus</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/okanagan">Okanagan Campus</a></div><h4>UBC Sites</h4><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/robson">Robson Square</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/centre-for-digital-media">Centre for Digital Media</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/medicine">Faculty of Medicine Across BC</a></div><div><a href="https://cdn.ubc.ca/clf/ref/asia">Asia Pacific Regional Office</a></div></div></div></'''

html = bs(site, 'html.parser')
link = html.find('a', string=re.compile('(?)(donate|donation|gift)')) 

#returns proper donation URL
```

However, using the site does not work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

site = requests.get('https://www.ubc.ca/')

html = bs(site.content, 'html.parser')
link = html.find('a', string=re.compile('(?i)(donate|donation|gift)')) 

#returns none
```

Is there something wrong with my parser? Is it some-sort of anti-scrape maneuver? Am I doomed?

Comment: I see no Donate button when viewing in a browser and when viewing the source of the page `span7` is empty.

Comment: There is also a good chance the button is injected by javascript, in which case, yes you are doomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot seem to find the 'Donate' button on the URL that you provided, but there is nothing inherently wrong with your parser, its just that the GET request that you send only gives you the HTML initially returned from the response, rather than waiting for the page to fully render.

It appears that parts of the page are filled in by Javascript. You can use [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is used to render Javascript-based pages. You can run Splash in [Docker](https://www.docker.com/community-edition) quite easily, and just make HTTP requests to the Splash container which will return HTML that looks just like the webpage as rendered in a web browser.

Although this sounds overly complicated, it is actually quite simple to set up since you don't need to modify the Docker image at all, and you need no previous knowledge of Docker to get it to work. It requires just a single line from the command line to start a local Splash server:
`docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash`

You then just modify any existing requests you have in your Python code to route to splash instead:

i.e. `http://example.com/` becomes
`http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://example.com/`